# How to hide then restore to initial state (= not always "block")?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here's the JavaScript code you can find everywhere when you want to hide/show an element:

```
function sh(_id, _val) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(_id).style.display = _val;
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { 
            document._id.display = _val;
        }
        else { 
            document.all._id.style.display = _val;
        }
    }
}
function hide(_id) {
    sh(_id, 'none');
}
function show(_id) {
    sh(_id, 'block');
}
```

The problem is the "show" function: it forces to "**`block`**". If I use a table with `tr`'s and `td`'s, when I want to display them I don't them to be displayed as "**`block`**" but to **restore to their initial state**.

How should I do?

How would you do?

Comment: If you want the default `display` value, you can assign an empty string to it. If you want the one assigned through CSS for example, you have to store it somewwere (e.g. in an `id -> display` map).

Comment: @FelixKling you're right! Please post your comment as an answer I'll check it ;)

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use CSS classes to hide/show. A "hidden" class would hide the element, then removing the class would restore the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to restore their *default* `display` value, you can assign an empty string to it:

```
element.style.display = '';
```

If you want the one assigned through CSS for example, you have to store it somewhere, e.g. in an `id -> display` map or as `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use jQuery and .show() http://api.jquery.com/show/

The second easiest way would be to wrap the table in a div.

If not I would try to store the initial value of display somewhere (if html5 the a "data-" attribute) if not in some other hidden element

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to avoid jQuery because my website has to be as light as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the point of your exercise is to learn more about DOM, then you may disregard this answer.  But if the point is to get some UI to work, then:

My suggestion would be to use jquery.  If you did, all of the code you showed would disappear altogether, and you would hide/show elements like this:

```
$('#' + id).hide()
$('#' + id).show()
```

If you want to stick with low level DOM api, then you'll have to save away the prior value (block or whatever) of style.display, so you can restore it later.  And you can do that.  But you'll keep having to write code like that, considering all kinds of cases, when someone has already written code that does that, and they're giving it away for free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to avoid jQuery because my website has to be as light as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousDisplay = {};
function sh(_id, _val) {
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById(_id).style.display = _val;
    }
    else {

        if (document.layers) { 
if(!previousDisplay[_id]){
          previousDisplay[_id] = document._id.display;
        }
            document._id.display = _val;
        }
        else { 
if(!previousDisplay[_id]){
          previousDisplay[_id] = document.all._id.style.display;
        }
            document.all._id.style.display = _val;
        }
    }
}
function hide(_id) {
    sh(_id, 'none');
}
function show(_id) {
    var style = previousDisplay[_id];
    if(!style){
     style = 'block';
    }
    sh(_id, style );
}
```